# Git commit --amend alias hangs

Tags: git, git-config, git-amend, git-alias

I have this alias in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    am = commit -a --amend -C HEAD
```

Yet, when I run `git am`, it hangs, and I get `(master|AM/REBASE)` at the prompt, and I have to run `git am --abort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There already is a [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) command. Your alias is invalid (since there already is such a command), and when you run `git am`, you're actually executing this command. If you chose a different alias, such as `ca` (short for "commit amend"), it should work:

```
[alias]
    ca = commit -a --amend -C HEAD
```

As a side note, `git commit` has a `--no-edit` flag you can use instead of `-C HEAD`:

```
[alias]
    ca = commit -a --amend --no-edit
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) command that Applies (patches from) Mailbox. In git aliases cannot override standard commands, so even if you have an alias `git am` runs the standard command and the command awaits input at the standard input. So it doesn't hang, it's just waiting.

Rename the alias to something not already among standard git commands.